# Blazor WebAssembly how to fix 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to call an API in Blazor WebAssembly  like this:

```
public async Task<string?> MakeReservation(MakeReservationModel model)
{
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        var _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        var jsoncontent = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("xyz/api/pianeta/zyx", jsoncontent);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urhmA.png) error:

> 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try using http rather than https

Comment: A quick research about your issue tends to point to CORS or something wrong in URL: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311181/getting-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-error-when-trying-to-call-aspnetcore-restfu), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084846/how-to-resolve-typeerror-failed-to-fetch-error-on-blazor), [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72359131/blazor-httprequestexceptiontypeerrorfailed-to-fetch), etc...

Comment: Inspect the InnerException

Answer (score 0):

I had a test in my side with a blazor web assembly standalone prject + .net 7 web api, and it worked for me.

[image]

So the first I think we could try to check the console window in the browser to see if there's a Cors error. For example if I comment the cors policy in my api, I can reproduce the issue like this.

[image]

If we already enabled the Cors policy in the API, then we need to see if the Cors exception still existed, if it didn't exist but still have the `Failed to fetch` error, we need to see if the request already reached the API and let's see if the API returned correct response.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in other methods but failed, if I misunderstood your requirement or the cors policy didn't help you, please share more details about your blazor app and your API.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with a Blazor WebAssembly PWA and an ASP.Net Core WEB API, both with .Net 8, and the problem was that I was missing one instruction.

In my WEB API Program.cs, only have:

```
    ...
    builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            policy => {
                policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7089")
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials();
            });
    });
    ...
    var app = builder.Build();
    ...
```

BUT the instruction that was missing goes after the builder.Build();

```
    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```